# PYODBC error in querying POSIXct datetime column in SQLServer2012

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm using Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit), sqlalchemy and pyodbc to query MSSQL 2012 Server. I can query any column, but not columns with POSIXct times.

This is the error I am getting. It appears the error is caused by pyodbc.

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('ODBC SQL type -155 is
>   not yet supported.  column-index=0  type=-155', 'HY106')

```
pyodbc Version: 4.0.14
```

Here is my code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

engine = sq.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sqlservertest/Mart?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
m = sq.MetaData(engine) 
insurance = sq.Table('Insurance', m, autoload=True, schema="Insurance", autoload_with=engine)
stmt = sq.select([insurance.c.ModifiedAt])
df = pd.read_sql(stmt, engine)
```

The column I am trying to query looks like this:

```
ModifiedAt
2016-04-01 23:24:08.0000000 -06:00
2016-04-01 23:37:27.0000000 -06:00
2016-04-01 23:31:01.0000000 -06:00
2016-04-02 09:39:38.0000000 -06:00
2016-04-04 10:26:34.0000000 -10:00
2016-04-04 11:10:20.0000000 -10:00
2016-04-04 11:32:54.0000000 -10:00
2016-04-04 11:42:04.0000000 -10:00
2016-04-04 11:48:19.0000000 -10:00
2016-04-05 08:32:38.0000000 -10:00
```

How can I approach to solve this?

Comment: Try using the older "SQL Server" driver (`... ?driver=SQL+Server'`) and see if you get the datetimeoffset values back as strings.

Comment: @GordThompson, It worked!! Thank you so much